# Lucene sort by country

Tags: java, sorting, lucene

I am trying to upgrade my lucene from 3.0 to 4.9. I wrote a custom sort by country which simply checked to see if the country was the same as the query was looking for, followed by how close the continent of the document was to the continent that the query was looking for.

It is not a filter - I want all the results, just sorted by country.

for example - I am looking for shoe stores and I am in the US.

so all the shoe stores in the US would be first, followed by Canada, Mexico, UK, Russia &c.

My Custom sort isn't compiling and I can't find any examples of how to write custom sorts in lucene 4.X.

I looked into geospatial search but that also appears to filter first, then sort.

Can anyone help me with an example of a custom sort for lucene 4.X?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe, this problem is better seen as a scoring problem, instead of a sorting problem. In this way, the question become: how to use the distance between countries (instead of df/idf metrics) to score your documents. Once they are scored properly, the default sorting method will be suitable.

Basically, it's necessary to extend [CustomScoreQuery](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_9_0/queries/org/apache/lucene/queries/CustomScoreQuery.html) and [CustomScoreProvider](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_9_0/queries/org/apache/lucene/queries/CustomScoreProvider.html) classes.

This blog post ([Lucene Custom Scoring](http://blog.imaginea.com/custom-scoring-custom-score-query-and-custom-score-provider/)) shows an example of extension.

To be a little more precise, my suggestion is:

1- Add "the distance knowledge" in your extended ***CustomScoreProvider***;

2- In the overridden ***customScore*** method, retrieve the document's country;

3- Calculate the distance between the document's country and query's country (remember to put this information through the CustomScoreQuery);

4- Return your score :)

I hope this strategy fits for you.

P.S. The blog post is related to version 4.6. Some adjusts may be necessary to work correctly with version 4.9.

Comment: Thanks. I actually have started using solr and just used their sort by a function to do it. it is a little simplistic but gets the job done:

if(termfreq(country,$country),-1,abs(sub(field(continent),$continent))) asc